# repeated error Cannot read property 'PayPalMobile' of undefined

Tags: paypal, cordova-3

Hi I am trying to use phonegap paypal android plugin
I am aware of the same issue raised on git hub but for previous version https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK-PhoneGap/issues/1

I did make the changes mentioned in readme that is

```
  <feature name="PayPalMobile"> 
          <param name="android-package" value="com.paypal.android.sdk.phonegap.PayPalMobilePGPlugin" />
 </feature>
```

in file

but i am getting the same error
[image: confix.xml]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you edit the correct config.xml `res/xml/config.xml`